# discrete variables

Tags: statistics

Am I correct with the following reasoning?

If P(X=a) = 0, then X must be a continuous variable. Since P(X=a) > 0, X must be discrete. The definition of discrete variable tells us that there must exist a countable set $E \subset R$ such that $P(X \in E) = 1$?

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of $A$ it follows directly that $A$ is *not* an uncountable set.

Observe that $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where $A_n:=\{a\in\mathbb R\mid P(X=a)>\frac1n\}$ where $|A_n|\leq n$, so $A$ appears to be a countable union of finite sets, hence is countable.

Further:

- $X$ is a continuous random variable if and only if $A=\varnothing$.
- $X$ is a discrete random variable if and only if $P(X\in A)=1$.

Comment: Re: your third bullet, random variables obey the rule continuous + discrete = continuous. I think you mean the _distribution_ of $X$ is a sum of a discrete measure and a continuous measure, or that $X$ is a mixture of continuous variable with a discrete variable. Also, $X$ need not be in this form, e.g. the Cantor distribution.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you. I removed the first bullet and will not say things about the distribution here.

Comment: If each $A_n$ is set of real numbers, how come the cardinality of An would be less than or equal to n. Shouldn't it be uncountably infinitely many? Thanks.

Comment: It is even stronger: $|A_n|<n$. Suppose that $B=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subseteq A_n$ where the $a_i$ are distinct. Then $P(X\in B)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(X=a_i)>\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1n>1$ which is absurd. So set $A_n$ cannot contain subsets  that have cardinality $n$, hence must itself have cardinality $<n$.

Answer (score 1):

At least part of this is incorrect.  Let's consider a random variable that can yield any integer.  And the output of this random variable is determined by the roll of a die.  Then you see that the P( -1 ) = 0, but this is still a discrete random variable.